# Edit uget queuing process

Tags: 14.04, uget

I would like to know how to edit the queuing process for `uget`.

Some data:

- `uget` version 1.10.5
- Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS.

*I would like to set it to just download 1 file at a time then start the next file in the queue after finishing.*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please review my edits and for the future, put your question at the end in italics so it's easier for the experts on this site, to first get the data and then have the question fresh in their mind when answering?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is edit the category properties on the left sidebar.

It is listed as "Active Downloads".

You can also make multiple categories to have many default settings based on a lot of features.

Answer (score 0):

Following answer applies to v2.2.1 (on Windows, but i assume its the same on Ubuntu)

Open the dialog 'Category Properties' via

> Menu bar \ Category \ Properties

.
Under 'Category Settings' tab (or page):

Active downloads: 1. (defaulting was 3, change to 1).

Now whenever you add items for download, it should queue them, instead of downloading automatically.